# Why cannot create user or group in alfresco explorer

Tags: alfresco

I checked out the source code from public repository and then build the source code in eclipse and deployed to tomcat server.

In "share", all functionalities can be used and there is no problem.
In "explorer", cannot create user, groups, permission , space, content and so on.

I do not really know that whether source code is incomplete or not
and some configurations are missing or not.

Please give me right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you make sure you logged in in Explorer? You can't do most of those things as guest, only if you login first

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's not working if you don't provide details in your questions. When does the user creation process fail in Explorer? How does it fail? Does the wizard complete flawlessly but without the user being created? Does it present a wrong sequence of forms, or incomplete/corrupted forms? Does it show any error message? Did you plug the power cord?

Comment: Lol @ "Did you plug the power cord" question :)